# Erlang equivalents of Haskell where/partial/lambda

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, erlang

Coming from Haskell to play with Nitrogen and running into a few things I can't find examples of, so if somebody could help me out:

Haskell's where (and or let or any type of function nesting with access to parent variables) in erlang? How? Can you?

```
burnOrDie hotness = foldl1 (>>) $ map burn ["Jimmy", "Adam", "Gonzo"]
  where burn x
          | hotness < 3 = print $ x ++ ": Ouch!"
          | otherwise = print $ x ++ ": GAHHH! *die*"
```

Partial application? Haskell: `addOne = +1`

in-line lambda function? Haskell: `map (\x -> x+x) [1,2,3]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am no expert in erlang but I will try to answer.

### Nesting functions

```
out(A) ->
    X = A + 1,
    SQ = fun(C) -> C*C end,
    io:format("~p",[SQ(X)]).
```

here SQ function has access to parent variables.

### In Lambda

This is same as above, you can use `fun` to define your anonymous functions.

### Partial application

I don't think erlang has partial function application in any sane way. The only thing you can do is to wrap functions to return function.

```
add(X) -> 
    Add2 = fun(Y) -> X + Y end,
    Add2.
```

Now you can do something like

```
1> c(test).
{ok,test}
2> A=test:add(1).
#Fun<test.0.41627352>
3> A(2).
3
```

Comment: Looks like exactly the details I was looking for. I had a feeling that was the case with partial, you can always do partials with closures as you showed. One question, in your example of X do I have to use fun(something) to make X parameterized so lambdas are really the answer to all 3 of my questions?

Comment: `\x -> something` is same as `fun(X) -> something`. You can write functions not taking any argument too. So something like `fun() -> dosomthing with X' will also work because X will already be in the scope.

Comment: Does it have to be `SQ = fun(c) ->` or can you nest a function as `SQ(c) ->` ? Also can I put guards on nested functions something like `SQ = fun(c) when (c == 1) -> 1; fun(c) when (_) -> c*c.` or pattern matching overloads perhaps `SQ = fun(0) -> 0; fun(1) -> 1.`

Comment: Why don't you try and see. You can also read more about `fun` here http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/funs.html

Answer (score 4):

Erlang doesn't have nested functions in the sense that Haskell and other languages do. When @Satvik created a function using `SQ = fun(C) -> C*C end` he was creating a closure, or *fun* in Erlang, and not a nested function. The syntax `fun (...) -> ... end` creates a fun or closure. which is not really the same thing.

Partial evaluation as in Haskell does not exist in Erlang, though you can hack it using funs.

You define in-line lambdas (funs) with the `fun` syntax. So you map becomes:

```
lists:map(fun (X) -> X+X end, [1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
% partially evaluating a function of two arguments
partial_eval(F, X, Pos) -> case Pos of
                              1 -> fun(Y) -> F(X,Y) end;
                              2 -> fun(Y) -> F(Y,X) end
                            end.

partial_eval(F,X) -> partial_eval(F,X,1).
```

With the above code in a module named `test.erl`, at the console:

```
7> c(test).
{ok,test}
8> Sum = fun(X,Y) -> X + Y end.
#Fun<erl_eval.13.126501267>
9> PS = test:partial_eval(Sum,3).
#Fun<test.1.126208848>
10> PS(4).
7
11> (test:partial_eval(Sum,3))(4). % can be invoked directly too
7
12> Div = fun(X,Y) -> X/Y end.
#Fun<erl_eval.13.126501267>
13> (test:partial_eval(Div,27))(3).
9.0
14> (test:partial_eval(Div,10,2))(3). % partial evaluation of second parameter
0.3
```